# jQuery map to create radio buttons- how to check first?

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery map to populate some radio buttons:

```
var radios = data.msg.map(function(datum) {
    var label = $('<label>').addClass('uit-option gblock').text(' '+datum.Name + ' $' + datum.Charge),
    input = $('<input>').attr({
        type: 'radio',
        name: 'ShippingMethod',
        checked: 'checked',
        value: datum.ID
    }),

    span = $('<span>').addClass('radio-option');

    $('#ShippingOptions').append(label.prepend(input, span));

}); // end radios
```

How can I use this to add `checked="checked"` to the first button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the index variable for the map function to set the first item

```
var radios = data.msg.map(function(datum, i) {
  var label = $('<label>').addClass('uit-option gblock').text(' '+datum.Name + ' $' + datum.Charge),
  input = $('<input>').attr({
    type: 'radio',
    name: 'ShippingMethod',
    value: datum.ID
  }),
  span = $('<span>').addClass('radio-option');

  if(i===0)
      input.attr('checked','checked'); //if index equals 0 add the checked attribute

  $('#ShippingOptions').append(label.prepend(input, span));

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Should not be using MAP for the output that you need. MAP is to create a subset of an array for each element of the original array. [Refer this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). You should be using a forEach loop here and the index arg of the callback can be used to add the checked attribute for the first element.